# How do I deploy docker web services on a local unix machine?

Tags: centos, cloud

I have the following situation. I have a CentOS machine that is currently providing a few Flask applications on different subdirectories (e.g. http://address/app1, http://address/app2 etc.). Users will come up with additional applications, possibly using different frameworks and dependencies.

This situation does not scale in the direction I want. What I would like to have is that every application is packaged into a docker container, and to deploy it, the users simply packages the image and push it.

Basically a cloud provider of some sort, but implemented in-house.

I understand that this requires some work with reverse proxying and it can be done by hand, but I suspect there's already a (lightweight) solution out there. I am not an expert on this topic, hence I need a few keyword for the appropriate technology for our IT to deploy on the CentOS machine and for me to study.

Note that I can't afford complex cloud services. I need something simple that targets my use case and can be deployed in an afternoon.

Comment: So you want docker to create containers automatically when they push an image to a repo?

Comment: @GregL yes, that's would work, but the repo must be internal (e.g. not docker hub). Basically they create a dockerfile, push it somewhere, the magic tool I am looking for downloads the new dockerfile, builds the docker image, and starts a container with the contents running, all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with quite a small footprint. You do not even need a registry or such a thing. But to be honest, I don't know a turnkey solution for that. This is what I would do:

Basically, you need to create a Dockerfile for each application. This allows you to create you containers, one per application. I have no idea about flask, but this will probably help you: [Dockerize your Flask Application](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-flask-application)

At the end of above linked article, there is also the command how to run it. What they don't explain (but you may need to know) ist, that this command forwards port 5000 from your local machine to port 5000 of your container. Therefore, you'll have to alter the port for each container, because two can not run simultaneously on the same port.

If you have dependencies between your containers, or many containers to start, you may want to take a look at [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

What you probably also need is a reverse proxy. And if you are on the path to containerize everything, why not also containerize that? You may even put it into the same docker-compose file which is at the end all you need. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://dev.to/domysee/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-with-nginx-and-docker-compose-29jg) for more information.

Last, but not least: To have that as a system service, [make a Systemd-Service](https://techoverflow.net/2018/12/15/a-systemd-service-template-for-docker-compose/) for it.

Next steps: Possible improvements are your own registry and automated builds ;-)